# possible lossy conversion from double to int

Tags: java

Write a program that contains two overloaded methods that return the average of an array with the following headers:

```
public static int average(int[] array)
public static double average(double[] array)
```

my program contains the errors

```
list2[i] = sc.nextDouble(); // possible lossy conversion from double to int 
return average;   // possible lossy conversion from double to int
```

not sure what the problem is I have declared within my methods what needs to be declared I don't know why my double in put would give me that error

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab7A {

public static void Main(String[] args) {


    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);



    System.out.print("Enter 10 Integer values: ");
    int list[] = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        list[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }

    double avg1 = average(list);
    System.out.println("Average of First Array: " + avg1);
    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("Enter Ten Double Values: ");
    double list2[] = new double[10];
    for (double i = 0; i < list2.length; i++) {
        list2[i] = sc.nextDouble();
    }

    double avg2 = average(list2);
    System.out.println("Average of Second Array: " + avg2);
    System.out.println();
    }
    public static int average(int[] list) {
    double average = 0;
    double total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        total = total + list[i];
    }
    average = total / list.length;
    return average;

}

 public static double average(double[] list2) {
    double average = 0;
    double total = 0;

   for (int i = 0; i < list2.length; i++) {
        total = total + list2[i];
    }
    average = total / list2.length;
    return average;
  }

 }
```

Comment: array positions are integer, but `d` in `list2[d]` is not an int. The error could be clearer, but it's not about what you're putting into the array, it's about you using a double as array index.

Comment: Why do you declare local variables named "average" and "total" in main() and never use them? And then you also call methods named "average".

Answer (score 1):

Your `average(double[])` method is attempting to use a `double` as an array index, but Java only allows `int`s as an array index.  This is the source of the "possible lossy conversion from double to int".

Everything else is and should be `double`, but declare your index `d` as `int` to remove this error.

Additionally, in the `for` loop of that method, the condition should be `d < list2.length` instead of `d < 5`.

Also, the average of `int` values may not necessarily be an `int`.  In your `average(int[])` method, declare it to return a `double`, and declare `average` to be a `double`.  The variable `avg1` will need to be a `double` in `main` also.

Comment: where exacly should I put the int instead of the d?

Comment: `int d = 0;` in the `for` loop instead of `double d = 0;`.

Comment: for (double d = 0; d < 5; d++) {
            total = total + list2[int];     gives me a '.class' expected error

Comment: i fixed my code but get the errors, I put it in my first post